Connecting Pi Pico W to my RN CLI app using BLE
I want to connect my pico w to react native cli app using BLE. for this native side i am using BLE- PLX library.
In Pico W, I have simply used the common examples of BLE in Pico W on the internet.
Here is the code:
# Import necessary modules
from machine import Pin 
import bluetooth
from ble_simple_peripheral import BLESimplePeripheral

# Create a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) object
ble = bluetooth.BLE()
# Create an instance of the BLESimplePeripheral class with the BLE object
sp = BLESimplePeripheral(ble,"PICO W")
# Create a Pin object for the onboard LED, configure it as an output
led = Pin("LED", Pin.OUT)
# Initialize the LED state to 0 (off)
led_state = 0

# Define a callback function to handle received data
def on_rx(data):
    print("Data received: ", data)  # Print the received data
    global led_state  # Access the global variable led_state
    if data == b'toggle\r\n':  # Check if the received data is "toggle"
        led.value(not led_state)  # Toggle the LED state (on/off)
        led_state = 1 - led_state  # Update the LED state

# Start an infinite loop
while True:
    if sp.is_connected():  # Check if a BLE connection is established
        sp.on_write(on_rx)  # Set the callback function for data reception

These are the libraries i have used:-  HERE
My problem is the object which I am getting after scanning the device in my RN app. I am not getting the characteristicUUID, which I require to receive & send data.
Then I checked the libraries of Pico W, and found that in those libraries there is not code for characteristicUUID..
Do anyone knows what can I do in this situation?
I tried adding custom UUID in the ble_simple_pheripheral library, but didn't worked.

Have you tried this service UUID here? https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/examples/bluetooth/ble_simple_peripheral.py#L25
Which services are currently active on your Pico, please check this using a generic BLE exploration tool such as nRF Connect

Yes , Service UUID is working.  Is either of them are needed for connection & data transfer or both are needed ?

All of the actually. As you know, BLE devices offer services that consist of one or more characteristics you can read/write. You should be able to read from (or better, activate notifcations on) the TX characteristic (6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E) and write to RX (6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E). You can test this using nRF Connect
